# CSS alignment issue in my header

Tags: html, css

as you can see on the picture below, my menu is +/- centered in the middle of the page whereas I would like it to be much further right (i.e. 20px to the left of the social icons).
I can not reproduce this on jsfiddle so I'm posting the [link of the page](http://goo.gl/XhS7EH) (also code would be too long to post here). Any thoughts on this issue and how to fix it? (note that I'm using safari latest version and that you need your screen to be at least 1600 wide to notice this)
Many thanks

[image]

An here is a mockup of how I would like it to be:

[image]

Comment: Looks fine on FF23. What browser are you using

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I'm using safari latest version. Note that to notice this you need at least to be 1600px wide

Comment: I am a little unclear as to what you are actually trying to have it look like, can you do a quick mock up image? You want that 4 column menu to be just 20px from the left of the social icons right? Under the red text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only see his issue on a much larger window size. The issue is with the div `#espace-entreprises` it is floated right. If you change it to be position `absolute` you will be fine.

```
#espace-entreprises {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

The issue is that when the window is wide enough `#main` and `#escape-entreprises` can actually float next to each other.  Then you notice the large 120px margin.

Also you might reduce the `margin-right` on `#menu`

Comment: Thanks Jon. That solved an issue but I've noticed another one now. When the black bar at the top of the page fades-in, the menu gets pushed to the left by 100px or something (to the edge of the red text "Entreprises: Cliquez ici...) and after 10 secs when the top bar fades out the menu gets back to the correct position. Any thoughts on this? Many thanks

Comment: Sure just did. Actually it looks OK with firefox. Just experiencing this issue with safari (latest version)

Comment: looks good in Chrome, I didn't notice anything jumping around